# Repeat Maple Piecewise Plot

Tags: plot, maple, piecewise

I have:

```
h(t):=piecewise(0<=t<2,2-t,2<=t<=3,2t-4)
```

Then I use:

```
plot(h(t),t=0..6,y=-1..3,scaling=constrained)
```

My intention was to create a period of 2 by making a larger interval. This didn't solved my problem.

How would I be able to create two periods in the plot?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I've understood the goal.

```
restart;

h:=t->piecewise(0<=t and t<2,2-t,2<=t and t<=3,2*t-4):

H:=proc(t,p::realcons)
     local P,T;
     if not t::realcons then
       return 'procname'(args);
     end if;
     P:=evalf(p);
     T:=frem(t-P/2,P)+P/2;
     h(T);
end proc:

plot(H(t,3), t=0..6, y=-1..3);
```

[image]

```
plot(H(t,3), t=-12..12, y=-1..3);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there, Acer! Awesome! But how did you knew how to make that "proc" thing? Is that just about training in Maple? Will that "proc" thing work every time I have to make a repeated plot of a piecewise? :-)

Comment: Being periodic means that any real point has to map back into the original domain. So I wrote a procedure to do that. The second parameter `p` allows you to pass in the period (ie. arbitrarily). If you change the definition of that proc so that it also accepts `h` as a 3rd parameter then it'd be more general purpose. (Currently it also assumes an original domain with zero as left end point, but it could also be adjusted for domain `a` to `b` arbitrarily.) Programming is the most powerful thing about Maple.

Comment: Hi Acer.. Same problem has arisen with other parameters :-( Now I have three functions in the "h(t)" and the plot won't show any graph beneath x = 0 with your script from earlier. Could you please help me generate a more general script to plot all these kinds of functions? :)

Comment: Please add your followup example, in 1D Maple Notation (plaintext format). By that I mean valid 1D code like `0<=t and t<2` rather than the `0<=t<2` which is merely what you see from the prettyprinted 2D Math. Use the `lprint` command on the `piecewise`, if don't know how to see it in 1D code form.

Comment: Hi Acer, problems again.. :-( I have tried to post an image in my comment to my thread.